# Why not hide the reps of an answerer to avoid unfair judgement of the answer?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

See the answer by @Brythan here:

[Why is North Korea criticized for having Nuclear Weapons?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/19130/why-is-north-korea-criticized-for-having-nuclear-weapons)

This is an answer that is is in many ways misinformed, opinionated, and, it probably classifies as biased and propagandaic as well.

1. Brythan states that "it is simply not true" that North Korea are not part of the Nuclear Non-Profileration treaty .... well, he is **completely** wrong, since they actually aren't part of it, and not only is he wrong, but the question actually asserts (correctly) that NK are not part of the treaty, so the fact that he still claims so in his answer suggests that he completely disregarded the questioner's claim and wrote the answer without first researching the matter. So, he exhibits both **misinformedness** and **closed-mindedness**.
2. He states that US did not breach the "no first strike" policy. Again, he is **completely** wrong. In fact, he does not even understand what "no first strike" refers to. It refers to no first strike with a NUCLEAR weapon.
3. The remaining part of his answer is completely opinionated and is not a rational, objective answer to the question being asked.

And, yes, this answer has 7 upvotes. Clearly, the people who upvoted this did so because Brythan has many reps.

So, should reps and names be hidden from users for some time after the answer, such that people can judge the answer on its own merit, rather than being influenced by *who* wrote the answer?

I do not doubt that Brythan contributes in positive ways to the site, but in this case, he wrote an atrocious answer, and to see it get 7 upvotes is pretty ridiculous.

Comment: Re: "Nuclear Non-Profileration", he claims that NK is **in** the treaty and provides a source to back up that claim, which is from the un.org website. Seems legitimate to me? If he is wrong, then feel free to correct him by adding a comment. Preferably with a better source and without resorting to personal attacks. The same applies tot he rest of your points.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker the source shows that NK is **not** in the treaty http://disarmament.un.org/treaties/a/npt/democraticpeoplesrepublicofkorea/acc/moscow (read the note)

Comment: @Federico Ah right, I just quickly checked that it's in the list.

Answer (score 5):

There is no point in arguing about this feature-request, because we can not fulfill it anyway. All stackexchange sites run on the same software. Stack Exchange Inc. generally does not develop individual features for individual sites, especially not when the site is still in beta.

If you want a change to the stackexchange software, you need to lobby for it on [the general stackexchange meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

Problems with this individual answer should be discussed in the comments on it (as people are already doing). I won't deny that people upvoting answers which contain factually wrong information is a problem. If you think we should tackle this problem, I would recommend that you open a new meta-question, but without proposing a solution right in the question. This would allow us to consider **all** the different approaches to the problem.